# Как в forms.Select django сделать, чтобы выбирался сразу первый пункт?

Tags: python, django, html-select

У меня в форме `select` показывает тире, и при нажатии уже идет выбор. Как убрать эти тире и чтобы сразу подставлял первый пункт?

**forms**

```
 class RelatedAddForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs=
{'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'on'}), queryset=None)
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
            super(RelatedAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['name'].queryset = getStoresListByUser(user=self.request.user)
            self.fields['name'].label = 'Склад'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В форму добавить:

```
self.fields['name'].empty_label = None
```

empty_label отвечает за значение по умолчанию.

​

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]